# Insertion Overload with String to Object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, insertion

New to C++ here. I have project that I am working on that
is asking me to overload the insertion operator like this:

```
someObject << “stringOne” << “stringTwo” << stringThree <<;
```

The idea of this line of code is essentially adding some strings to an array that ‘someObject
’ holds.

I am aware that the prototype for insertion overload is like this, but I am not sure how to define the actual function so it works like how I mentioned above.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const someClass& classObj);
```

All the examples that I have seen online always have the ‘ostream& identifier’ as the left operand & the object as the right, like this
‘os << someObject’ so I am unsure on how to make it work like how I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just make `operator<<` a member function to get the syntax you want:

```
someClass& operator<<(std::string str) {
    // add the string to this
    return *this;
}
```

and you can do:

```
someObject << "hello" << "world";
```

You can add additional overloads for any other types you want on the right hand side.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Hd2aK3).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to overload insertion operator for your class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:

  A & operator <<(const std::string & s) {
    v.push_back(s);
    return *this;
  }

  void print() const {
    for (auto & s: v) {
      cout << "element:" << s << endl;
    }
  }

private:
  vector<string> v;
};

int main() {
  A a;
  string s = "string object";

  a << "test" << "string" << s;

  a.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called "chaining" and  the examples you saw are self-explanatory. A chained operator acts on reference to object and argument and returns reference to object.

```
DataList &  operator<<(DataList &out, const Data &arg)
{
     // insert arg into out
     return out; 
}
```

In this case

```
someObject << “stringOne” << “stringTwo” << stringThree;
```

works  as if

```
((someObject << “stringOne”) << “stringTwo”) << stringThree;
```